# How to start listing keys after a new line in a block

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Using the built-in yaml package in Python is it possible to dump the items of a list starting in a new line after the list indicator dash?

Instead of this structure:

```
root:
  - name: a
    id: 0
  - name: b
    id: 1
```

I need the following structure:

```
root:
  -
    name: a
    id: 0
  -
    name: b
    id: 1
```

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: Mostly readability, it's easier to read the items in the blocks when blocks are further away from each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK PyYAML doesn't even support the first output that you indicate:

```
import sys
import yaml as pyyaml

data = dict(root=[dict(name="a", id=0), dict(name="b", id=1)])
pyyaml.safe_dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False, indent=4)
```

as this gives:

```
root:
-   id: 0
    name: a
-   id: 1
    name: b
```

As you can see the block sequence item indicator (`-`) is not
offset within the indent of the sequence item, and to do that and/or to get the
extra line newline, you would have to change theinternals of PyYAML's emitter.

The other built-in YAML library, `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), can
do exactly what you want:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = dict(root=[dict(name="a", id=0), dict(name="b", id=1)])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.compact_seq_map = False

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
root:
  -
    name: a
    id: 0
  -
    name: b
    id: 1
```

BTW I would call neither PyYAML nor `ruamel.yaml` *built-in*, whatever
you mean by that. Python has a standard library (as it comes with
batteries included), which e.g. contains a JSON parser. But there is
no YAML parser in the standard library.

Comment: With the followin code the indentation can be fixed, but not a new line problem
class MyDumper(yaml.Dumper):
    def increase_indent(self, flow=False, indentless=False):
        return super(MyDumper, self).increase_indent(flow, False)
#bysomeoneonstackoverflow

Comment: Well that is what I mean by changing the internals: there is no easy option to that effect for the PyYAML's `dump()` routine.